# MVC going to the wrong view using area in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an area name HR.  here is the HRAreaRegistration.CS

```
namespace WebApplication1.Areas.HR
{
    public class HRAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "HR";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
              "HR_default2",
              "HR/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
            context.MapRoute(
               "HR_default1",
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

        }
    }
}
```

in RouteConfig.cs

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "WebApplication1.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

I was hoping that since I prioritized the main controller namespace when I go to Home/Index I would hit the view and controller HomeController/Index.  Instead I am going to the Home Controller in the HR Area.  HR/HomeController/Index.  not sure what I am doing wrong.

here is home controller (the one I would like to hit when I go to Home/Index)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
```

and here is the home controller in the hr area (the one I am hitting when I go to Home/Index even though I shouldn't be)

```
 using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;

        namespace WebApplication1.Areas.HR.Controllers
        {
            public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                // GET: HR/Home
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
```

/***********Editing my question in response to pfx answer********************/

for this application if a certain variable is set then the default page should be in the HR area. specifically HR area Controller OST action Index.  so all of the following should take us to that view.

```
http://nrdephrs01/hrpa
http://nrdephrs01/hrpa/ost
http://nrdephrs01/hrpa/ost/index
http://nrdephrs01/hrpa/hr/ost/
http://nrdephrs01/hrpa/hr/ost/index
```

now when they get to this default page there is a link that is to take them to Users/Details/1524  so this controller is not in an area. it is just Controller = Users Action = Details.

here are my routes which work until I try to go to the Users/Details/1524 where it can not find the controller.

HRAreaRegistration

```
namespace Portal.UI.Areas.HR
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class HRAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "HR";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {

            context.MapRoute(
                "HR_default",
                "HR/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

            // if the application is Out of State travel there will be an appsetting called OST set to true.
            // for OST applications have the main default page be HR/OST/Index
            string ost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OST"];

            if (ost == "true")
            {
                context.MapRoute(
                "Details",
                 "Users/{action}/{id}",
                 new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

                context.MapRoute(
                 "HR_default1",
                  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  new { controller = "OST", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is RouteConfig.cs

```
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;

    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your `HR_default1` route registration is missing the area prefix. Just remove that `MapRoute` call

Comment: I don't want to prefix it with HR so that if there a controller action that is only in the HR area like HRHomeController I can hit it with both HR/HRHome/Index and HRHome/Index.  that is why I have the two routes

Comment: `HR_default1` configuration has same pattern as default route, this is redundant and should be removed. Why don't you try setting `HR/{action}/{id}` route?

Comment: when I remove HR_default 1 I cannot hit my HRHomeController with http://localhost:50908/HRHome/Index I can only hit it with http://localhost:50908/HR/HRHome/Index  when I put that route in I can hit it both ways. so I think I need the extra route

Comment: How about putting `new[] { "WebApplication1.Areas.HR.Controllers" }` inside `HR_default1` definition? Note that area route is placed in topmost order, therefore if you have same URL route path it matches the area route first instead of the default route.

Comment: tried this and the application no longer loads.

Comment: is there a way to have the area route not be placed in the topmost order?

Comment: Your update on the question again includes the `HR_default1` route, which will conflict with the same one in the default area. That route is not part of my answer; only the one with the `HR` area and the explicit `HRHome` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments I read that you want `http://localhost:50908/HRHome/Index` to be handled by the `HRHomeController`in the `HR` area.

To do so you have to define an explicit route in `HRAreaRegistration.cs` for `HRHome`, replacing `{controller}` with `HRHome` in the route template.

Having this route with an explicit and unique route template eliminates any conflicts with other routes, including those from the default area.

It is important to register this route from within the `AreaRegistration` instead of `RouteConfig`, otherwise the views don't get resolved from the appropriate `views` folder within the `HR` area.

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "HRHome"
    url: "HRHome/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "HRHome", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        },
    namespaces: new [] { "WebApplication1.Areas.HR.Controllers" }
    );
```

The full area registration looks like:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "HRHome"
        url: "HRHome/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "HRHome", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            },
        namespaces: new [] { "WebApplication1.Areas.HR.Controllers" }
        );


    context.MapRoute(
        name: "HR_default"
        url: "HR/{controller}/{action}/{id}",,
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "HRHome", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            },
        namespaces: new [] { "WebApplication1.Areas.HR.Controllers" }
        );
}
```

Comment: thank you I updated my question after attempting your solution. I am unable to hit the controller that is not in the HR area.

Comment: See my comment on the question about your routes setup.

Comment: thanks pfx that got me on the correct track. seems to be working now.   I can't award the bounty for 17 hours but then I will do so.

Comment: Your welcome! This was a really good brainteaser; an exceptional routing setup, but valid.

Comment: Good job holding your ground on the changes to the OP. Well earned bounty.

Comment: @Nkosi Appreciated!